# jbpm - cannot handle exceptions in subprocess as it immediately throws and exits

Tags: java, exception, quarkus, jbpm, kogito

I am using jbpm on *quarkus* with dependency **kogito-quarkus**.
I have a flow consists of ten steps and three of them may throw an exception called **ApplicationException**. So I added these three steps **compensations** so when there is an exception thrown, I wanted to redo another operations below these operations.
In order to catch exceptions on bpmn2 file, I created a subprocess *Handle Error* and tried to catch the exception and after I put **End Compensation** event that will trigger other compensation events(I hoped), but it did not work. When the exception thrown, process immediately stops and does not enter the subprocess. I am sure that **ApplicationException** path is correct. I am sharing my bpmn2 file, all comments appreciated.
Please note that I *throw new ApplicationException("...");* when a problem occurs, and I was hoping to see the subprocess start when the exception thrown. But It returns the exception logs and stops the process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:bpsim="http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:drools="http://www.jboss.org/drools" xmlns:xsi="xsi" id="_yYuL4B2fEDuQ4oFmmBrvbQ" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd http://www.jboss.org/drools drools.xsd http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0 bpsim.xsd http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC DC.xsd http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI DI.xsd " exporter="jBPM Process Modeler" exporterVersion="2.0" targetNamespace="http://www.omg.org/bpmn20">
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="_userItem" structureRef="org.robolaunch.models.User"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="_passwordItem" structureRef="String"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="_defaultOrgNameItem" structureRef="String"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="_organizationItem" structureRef="org.robolaunch.models.Organization"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_userInputXItem" structureRef="org.robolaunch.models.User"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_passwordOutputXItem" structureRef="String"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_defaultOrgNameInputXItem" structureRef="String"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_organizationOutputXItem" structureRef="org.robolaunch.models.Organization"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_userInputXItem" structureRef="org.robolaunch.models.User"/>
  <bpmn2:itemDefinition id="__BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_defaultOrgNameInputXItem" structureRef="String"/>
  <bpmn2:interface id="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D_ServiceInterface" name="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" implementationRef="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService">
    <bpmn2:operation id="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D_ServiceOperation" name="errorHandler" implementationRef="errorHandler"/>
  </bpmn2:interface>
  <bpmn2:error id="org.robolaunch.exception.ApplicationException" errorCode="org.robolaunch.exception.ApplicationException"/>
  <bpmn2:interface id="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_ServiceInterface" name="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" implementationRef="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService">
    <bpmn2:operation id="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_ServiceOperation" name="createRegisteredUserWithPassword" implementationRef="createRegisteredUserWithPassword"/>
  </bpmn2:interface>
  <bpmn2:interface id="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_ServiceInterface" name="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService" implementationRef="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService">
    <bpmn2:operation id="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_ServiceOperation" name="createRealmForDefaultOrganization" implementationRef="createRealmForDefaultOrganization"/>
  </bpmn2:interface>
  <bpmn2:interface id="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_ServiceInterface" name="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" implementationRef="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService">
    <bpmn2:operation id="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_ServiceOperation" name="deleteUserFromFreeIPA" implementationRef="deleteUserFromFreeIPA"/>
  </bpmn2:interface>
  <bpmn2:interface id="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_ServiceInterface" name="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService" implementationRef="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService">
    <bpmn2:operation id="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_ServiceOperation" name="deleteRealmForDefaultOrganization" implementationRef="deleteRealmForDefaultOrganization"/>
  </bpmn2:interface>
  <bpmn2:collaboration id="_FFD70CE4-A6A4-45FA-BF49-4DA11F162E4F" name="Default Collaboration">
    <bpmn2:participant id="_35C47359-BB9D-4BAE-9018-5E828230916F" name="Pool Participant" processRef="userRegistration"/>
  </bpmn2:collaboration>
  <bpmn2:process id="userRegistration" drools:packageName="org.robolaunch.kogito.user.userRegistration" drools:version="1.0" drools:adHoc="false" name="userRegistration" isExecutable="true" processType="Public">
    <bpmn2:property id="user" itemSubjectRef="_userItem" name="user"/>
    <bpmn2:property id="password" itemSubjectRef="_passwordItem" name="password">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="customTags">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[internal]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    </bpmn2:property>
    <bpmn2:property id="defaultOrgName" itemSubjectRef="_defaultOrgNameItem" name="defaultOrgName">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="customTags">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[internal]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    </bpmn2:property>
    <bpmn2:property id="organization" itemSubjectRef="_organizationItem" name="organization">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="customTags">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[internal]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    </bpmn2:property>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="_D3B87383-C667-4CB8-869B-26E8CDBF1FE5" sourceRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992" targetRef="_91203359-7134-4E11-9BBD-7A813038CDE0">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="isAutoConnection.target">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[true]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    </bpmn2:sequenceFlow>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="_0D4CE231-1EE5-4E8F-8074-7790E613F17F" sourceRef="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C" targetRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992"/>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="_125FB73D-556C-4D70-AFE6-754475F76924" sourceRef="_BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D" targetRef="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="isAutoConnection.target">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[true]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    </bpmn2:sequenceFlow>
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="_91203359-7134-4E11-9BBD-7A813038CDE0">
      <bpmn2:incoming>_D3B87383-C667-4CB8-869B-26E8CDBF1FE5</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
    <bpmn2:serviceTask id="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E" drools:serviceimplementation="Java" drools:serviceinterface="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService" drools:serviceoperation="deleteRealmForDefaultOrganization" name="Delete Default organization's realm" isForCompensation="true" implementation="Java" operationRef="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_ServiceOperation">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="elementname">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Delete Default organization's realm]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpmn2:ioSpecification>
        <bpmn2:dataInput id="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_defaultOrgNameInputX" drools:dtype="String" itemSubjectRef="__BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_defaultOrgNameInputXItem" name="defaultOrgName"/>
        <bpmn2:inputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_defaultOrgNameInputX</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
        </bpmn2:inputSet>
      </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
      <bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>defaultOrgName</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E_defaultOrgNameInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
    </bpmn2:serviceTask>
    <bpmn2:serviceTask id="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272" drools:serviceimplementation="Java" drools:serviceinterface="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" drools:serviceoperation="deleteUserFromFreeIPA" name="Delete User From FreeIPA" isForCompensation="true" implementation="Java" operationRef="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_ServiceOperation">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="elementname">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Delete User From FreeIPA]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpmn2:ioSpecification>
        <bpmn2:dataInput id="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_userInputX" drools:dtype="org.robolaunch.models.User" itemSubjectRef="__D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_userInputXItem" name="user"/>
        <bpmn2:inputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_userInputX</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
        </bpmn2:inputSet>
      </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
      <bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>user</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272_userInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
    </bpmn2:serviceTask>
    <bpmn2:serviceTask id="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992" drools:serviceimplementation="Java" drools:serviceinterface="org.robolaunch.service.KeycloakService" drools:serviceoperation="createRealmForDefaultOrganization" name="Create default organization's realm on keycloak" implementation="Java" operationRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_ServiceOperation">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="elementname">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Create default organization's realm on keycloak]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpmn2:incoming>_0D4CE231-1EE5-4E8F-8074-7790E613F17F</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>_D3B87383-C667-4CB8-869B-26E8CDBF1FE5</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:ioSpecification>
        <bpmn2:dataInput id="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_defaultOrgNameInputX" drools:dtype="String" itemSubjectRef="__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_defaultOrgNameInputXItem" name="defaultOrgName"/>
        <bpmn2:dataOutput id="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_organizationOutputX" drools:dtype="org.robolaunch.models.Organization" itemSubjectRef="__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_organizationOutputXItem" name="organization"/>
        <bpmn2:inputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_defaultOrgNameInputX</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
        </bpmn2:inputSet>
        <bpmn2:outputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataOutputRefs>_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_organizationOutputX</bpmn2:dataOutputRefs>
        </bpmn2:outputSet>
      </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
      <bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>defaultOrgName</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_defaultOrgNameInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
      <bpmn2:dataOutputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_organizationOutputX</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>organization</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataOutputAssociation>
    </bpmn2:serviceTask>
    <bpmn2:serviceTask id="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C" drools:serviceimplementation="Java" drools:serviceinterface="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" drools:serviceoperation="createRegisteredUserWithPassword" name="Create User on FreeIPA" implementation="Java" operationRef="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_ServiceOperation">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="elementname">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Create User on FreeIPA]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpmn2:incoming>_125FB73D-556C-4D70-AFE6-754475F76924</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>_0D4CE231-1EE5-4E8F-8074-7790E613F17F</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:ioSpecification>
        <bpmn2:dataInput id="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_userInputX" drools:dtype="org.robolaunch.models.User" itemSubjectRef="__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_userInputXItem" name="user"/>
        <bpmn2:dataOutput id="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_passwordOutputX" drools:dtype="String" itemSubjectRef="__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_passwordOutputXItem" name="password"/>
        <bpmn2:inputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataInputRefs>_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_userInputX</bpmn2:dataInputRefs>
        </bpmn2:inputSet>
        <bpmn2:outputSet>
          <bpmn2:dataOutputRefs>_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_passwordOutputX</bpmn2:dataOutputRefs>
        </bpmn2:outputSet>
      </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
      <bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>user</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_userInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
      <bpmn2:dataOutputAssociation>
        <bpmn2:sourceRef>_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_passwordOutputX</bpmn2:sourceRef>
        <bpmn2:targetRef>password</bpmn2:targetRef>
      </bpmn2:dataOutputAssociation>
    </bpmn2:serviceTask>
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="_BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>_125FB73D-556C-4D70-AFE6-754475F76924</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:subProcess id="_168B5492-3A73-4D64-947B-3A5526A435DB" name="Handle Error" triggeredByEvent="true">
      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <drools:metaData name="elementname">
          <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Handle Error]]></drools:metaValue>
        </drools:metaData>
      </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="_A54BD2CA-81D2-421E-8A7E-9AD841BF692A" sourceRef="_205B4BBD-DE3D-48CA-95DD-94E295778A2D" targetRef="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D"/>
      <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="_8DDE6585-0B51-465B-9C80-AAFF2E782B10" sourceRef="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D" targetRef="_E5529222-60EC-4824-AAB5-0C4C1A83AA2D">
        <bpmn2:extensionElements>
          <drools:metaData name="isAutoConnection.target">
            <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[true]]></drools:metaValue>
          </drools:metaData>
        </bpmn2:extensionElements>
      </bpmn2:sequenceFlow>
      <bpmn2:startEvent id="_205B4BBD-DE3D-48CA-95DD-94E295778A2D" name="Application Exception">
        <bpmn2:extensionElements>
          <drools:metaData name="elementname">
            <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Application Exception]]></drools:metaValue>
          </drools:metaData>
        </bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <bpmn2:outgoing>_A54BD2CA-81D2-421E-8A7E-9AD841BF692A</bpmn2:outgoing>
        <bpmn2:errorEventDefinition drools:erefname="org.robolaunch.exception.ApplicationException" errorRef="org.robolaunch.exception.ApplicationException"/>
      </bpmn2:startEvent>
      <bpmn2:serviceTask id="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D" drools:serviceimplementation="Java" drools:serviceinterface="org.robolaunch.service.AccountService" drools:serviceoperation="errorHandler" name="Service Task" implementation="Java" operationRef="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D_ServiceOperation">
        <bpmn2:extensionElements>
          <drools:metaData name="elementname">
            <drools:metaValue><![CDATA[Service Task]]></drools:metaValue>
          </drools:metaData>
        </bpmn2:extensionElements>
        <bpmn2:incoming>_A54BD2CA-81D2-421E-8A7E-9AD841BF692A</bpmn2:incoming>
        <bpmn2:outgoing>_8DDE6585-0B51-465B-9C80-AAFF2E782B10</bpmn2:outgoing>
      </bpmn2:serviceTask>
      <bpmn2:endEvent id="_E5529222-60EC-4824-AAB5-0C4C1A83AA2D">
        <bpmn2:incoming>_8DDE6585-0B51-465B-9C80-AAFF2E782B10</bpmn2:incoming>
        <bpmn2:compensateEventDefinition activityRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992"/>
      </bpmn2:endEvent>
    </bpmn2:subProcess>
    <bpmn2:boundaryEvent id="_2AC856AB-AEAC-4FB2-A07D-E7F3AE334A9A" drools:dockerinfo="62.5934065934066^69|" attachedToRef="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C">
      <bpmn2:compensateEventDefinition/>
    </bpmn2:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn2:boundaryEvent id="_95B33EFD-1FFE-4634-B9F6-B152CC485DC9" drools:dockerinfo="73.88235294117646^55|" attachedToRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992">
      <bpmn2:compensateEventDefinition/>
    </bpmn2:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn2:association id="_175CFB83-1169-46BD-9758-A356DEAF21D2" associationDirection="One" sourceRef="_2AC856AB-AEAC-4FB2-A07D-E7F3AE334A9A" targetRef="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272"/>
    <bpmn2:association id="_EEF0E368-FFB3-4CA1-B181-4DC5BA047F41" associationDirection="One" sourceRef="_95B33EFD-1FFE-4634-B9F6-B152CC485DC9" targetRef="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E"/>
  </bpmn2:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="userRegistration">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__168B5492-3A73-4D64-947B-3A5526A435DB" bpmnElement="_168B5492-3A73-4D64-947B-3A5526A435DB" isExpanded="true">
        <dc:Bounds height="253" width="653" x="596.5" y="618"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__E5529222-60EC-4824-AAB5-0C4C1A83AA2D" bpmnElement="_E5529222-60EC-4824-AAB5-0C4C1A83AA2D">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="1060" y="717"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D" bpmnElement="_F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D">
        <dc:Bounds height="102" width="154" x="832" y="694"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__205B4BBD-DE3D-48CA-95DD-94E295778A2D" bpmnElement="_205B4BBD-DE3D-48CA-95DD-94E295778A2D">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="681.5" y="717"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D_to_shape__E5529222-60EC-4824-AAB5-0C4C1A83AA2D" bpmnElement="_8DDE6585-0B51-465B-9C80-AAFF2E782B10">
        <di:waypoint x="909" y="745"/>
        <di:waypoint x="1088" y="717"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__205B4BBD-DE3D-48CA-95DD-94E295778A2D_to_shape__F1374136-CEB8-45D3-89ED-CEFAE9B80C3D" bpmnElement="_A54BD2CA-81D2-421E-8A7E-9AD841BF692A">
        <di:waypoint x="709.5" y="745"/>
        <di:waypoint x="909" y="745"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__2AC856AB-AEAC-4FB2-A07D-E7F3AE334A9A" bpmnElement="_2AC856AB-AEAC-4FB2-A07D-E7F3AE334A9A">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="425.5934065934066" y="315"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__95B33EFD-1FFE-4634-B9F6-B152CC485DC9" bpmnElement="_95B33EFD-1FFE-4634-B9F6-B152CC485DC9">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="818.8823529411765" y="294"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D" bpmnElement="_BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="229" y="269"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C" bpmnElement="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C">
        <dc:Bounds height="97" width="162" x="363" y="246"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992" bpmnElement="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992">
        <dc:Bounds height="83" width="194" x="745" y="239"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272" bpmnElement="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272">
        <dc:Bounds height="102" width="154" x="377" y="401"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E" bpmnElement="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E">
        <dc:Bounds height="95" width="172" x="756" y="389"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="shape__91203359-7134-4E11-9BBD-7A813038CDE0" bpmnElement="_91203359-7134-4E11-9BBD-7A813038CDE0">
        <dc:Bounds height="56" width="56" x="1014" y="288"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__2AC856AB-AEAC-4FB2-A07D-E7F3AE334A9A_to_shape__D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272" bpmnElement="_175CFB83-1169-46BD-9758-A356DEAF21D2">
        <di:waypoint x="453.5934065934066" y="343"/>
        <di:waypoint x="454" y="401"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__95B33EFD-1FFE-4634-B9F6-B152CC485DC9_to_shape__BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E" bpmnElement="_EEF0E368-FFB3-4CA1-B181-4DC5BA047F41">
        <di:waypoint x="846.8823529411765" y="322"/>
        <di:waypoint x="842" y="389"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D_to_shape__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C" bpmnElement="_125FB73D-556C-4D70-AFE6-754475F76924">
        <di:waypoint x="257" y="297"/>
        <di:waypoint x="363" y="294.5"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C_to_shape__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992" bpmnElement="_0D4CE231-1EE5-4E8F-8074-7790E613F17F">
        <di:waypoint x="444" y="294.5"/>
        <di:waypoint x="842" y="280.5"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="edge_shape__3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992_to_shape__91203359-7134-4E11-9BBD-7A813038CDE0" bpmnElement="_D3B87383-C667-4CB8-869B-26E8CDBF1FE5">
        <di:waypoint x="842" y="280.5"/>
        <di:waypoint x="1014" y="316"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
  <bpmn2:relationship type="BPSimData">
    <bpmn2:extensionElements>
      <bpsim:BPSimData>
        <bpsim:Scenario id="default" name="Simulationscenario">
          <bpsim:ScenarioParameters/>
          <bpsim:ElementParameters elementRef="_BA24F379-902A-4417-BC75-93246128397D">
            <bpsim:TimeParameters>
              <bpsim:ProcessingTime>
                <bpsim:NormalDistribution mean="0" standardDeviation="0"/>
              </bpsim:ProcessingTime>
            </bpsim:TimeParameters>
          </bpsim:ElementParameters>
          <bpsim:ElementParameters elementRef="_B0DC523D-693D-4C46-BE8A-1AC9A8AE456C">
            <bpsim:TimeParameters>
              <bpsim:ProcessingTime>
                <bpsim:NormalDistribution mean="0" standardDeviation="0"/>
              </bpsim:ProcessingTime>
            </bpsim:TimeParameters>
            <bpsim:ResourceParameters>
              <bpsim:Availability>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Availability>
              <bpsim:Quantity>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Quantity>
            </bpsim:ResourceParameters>
            <bpsim:CostParameters>
              <bpsim:UnitCost>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:UnitCost>
            </bpsim:CostParameters>
          </bpsim:ElementParameters>
          <bpsim:ElementParameters elementRef="_3D2BA8B5-E4DC-4CE4-8397-D639987E4992">
            <bpsim:TimeParameters>
              <bpsim:ProcessingTime>
                <bpsim:NormalDistribution mean="0" standardDeviation="0"/>
              </bpsim:ProcessingTime>
            </bpsim:TimeParameters>
            <bpsim:ResourceParameters>
              <bpsim:Availability>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Availability>
              <bpsim:Quantity>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Quantity>
            </bpsim:ResourceParameters>
            <bpsim:CostParameters>
              <bpsim:UnitCost>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:UnitCost>
            </bpsim:CostParameters>
          </bpsim:ElementParameters>
          <bpsim:ElementParameters elementRef="_D9B7ACD2-5403-4592-A677-326118CE2272">
            <bpsim:TimeParameters>
              <bpsim:ProcessingTime>
                <bpsim:NormalDistribution mean="0" standardDeviation="0"/>
              </bpsim:ProcessingTime>
            </bpsim:TimeParameters>
            <bpsim:ResourceParameters>
              <bpsim:Availability>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Availability>
              <bpsim:Quantity>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Quantity>
            </bpsim:ResourceParameters>
            <bpsim:CostParameters>
              <bpsim:UnitCost>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:UnitCost>
            </bpsim:CostParameters>
          </bpsim:ElementParameters>
          <bpsim:ElementParameters elementRef="_BF23925A-0E27-4245-918E-DDB4D416FC9E">
            <bpsim:TimeParameters>
              <bpsim:ProcessingTime>
                <bpsim:NormalDistribution mean="0" standardDeviation="0"/>
              </bpsim:ProcessingTime>
            </bpsim:TimeParameters>
            <bpsim:ResourceParameters>
              <bpsim:Availability>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Availability>
              <bpsim:Quantity>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:Quantity>
            </bpsim:ResourceParameters>
            <bpsim:CostParameters>
              <bpsim:UnitCost>
                <bpsim:FloatingParameter value="0"/>
              </bpsim:UnitCost>
            </bpsim:CostParameters>
          </bpsim:ElementParameters>
        </bpsim:Scenario>
      </bpsim:BPSimData>
    </bpmn2:extensionElements>
    <bpmn2:source>_yYuL4B2fEDuQ4oFmmBrvbQ</bpmn2:source>
    <bpmn2:target>_yYuL4B2fEDuQ4oFmmBrvbQ</bpmn2:target>
  </bpmn2:relationship>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the service task in the `Handle Error` subprocess executed? The issue is just that the compensations are not executed after the `End Compensation` node, or does after the exception is thrown the subprocess is not started?

It seems you followed the pattern in https://blog.kie.org/2022/02/saga-pattern-with-processes-and-kogito-part-2.html.

Comment: Flow immediately stopped after seeing an exception and I was not able to see any process running. I solved it by using "DATA-DRIVEN FLOW WITH GATEWAYS" instead of exception driven flow. An example of it is also included in the link you sent. Thanks.